# Gulp tasks not waiting for another, not running in series

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have the following gulp file:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rev = require('gulp-rev');
var usemin = require('gulp-usemin');
var ngmin = require('gulp-ngmin');
var path = require('path');
var rimraf = require('gulp-rimraf');


var bases = {
 app: 'app/',
 dist: 'dist/'
};

var paths = {
  scripts: ['scripts/**/*.js', '!scripts/libs/**/*.js'],
  styles: ['styles/**/*.css'],
  html: ['index.html', '404.html'],
  views: ['views/**/*.html']
};


gulp.task('copy', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.views, {cwd: bases.app, read:false})
  .pipe(gulp.dest(bases.dist + '/views/'));
});

gulp.task('clean', function() {
  return gulp.src(bases.dist, { read: false }) // much faster
    .pipe(rimraf());
});


gulp.task('usemin', [], function () {
  return gulp.src('./*.html', {cwd: bases.app})
    .pipe(usemin({
      js: [/*uglify(), rev()*/]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(bases.dist));
});

// Rerun the task when a file changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(path.join(bases.app, paths.scripts[0]), ['usemin']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'usemin', 'copy']);
```

According to the documentation, returning a stream like I do, in the *clean* task, *copy* and *usemin* should be waiting for *clean* to complete.

As you can see from the console, they do not

```
[23:33:22] Starting 'clean'...
[23:33:22] Starting 'usemin'...
[23:33:22] Starting 'copy'...
[23:33:22] Finished 'clean' after 82 ms
[23:33:22] Finished 'copy' after 9.92 ms
[23:33:22] Finished 'usemin' after 200 ms
[23:33:22] Starting 'default'...
[23:33:22] Finished 'default' after 9.76 μs
```

the expected result would be something like:

```
[23:33:22] Starting 'clean'...
[23:33:22] Finished 'clean' after 82 ms
[23:33:22] Starting 'usemin'...
[23:33:22] Starting 'copy'...
[23:33:22] Finished 'copy' after 9.92 ms
[23:33:22] Finished 'usemin' after 200 ms
[23:33:22] Starting 'default'...
[23:33:22] Finished 'default' after 9.76 μs
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which part of the documentation are you referring?

Comment: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-tasks-in-series.md       ==> Another example, which returns the stream instead of using a callback:

Comment: "templates and styles will be processed in parallel"

Comment: Gulp will execute tasks concurrently, which is one of the proposed benefits over Grunt.

Comment: Try to specify prerequisite tasks for each. Ex: `usemin` should be executed after `clean`, so your `usemin` task should be described as `gulp.task('usemin', ['clean'], function () {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to the hint of zaynetro, I figured the obvious out..

the syntax of `gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'usemin', 'copy'], function() {})` just means, *default* depends on *clean*, *usemin* and *copy*, regardless of their order. They will all be processed concurrently.

If you really want to have control over the task exceution order, you have to break it down into subtasks that depend on *clean* in my case themselfs like:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rev = require('gulp-rev');
var usemin = require('gulp-usemin');
var ngmin = require('gulp-ngmin');
var path = require('path');
var rimraf = require('gulp-rimraf');


var bases = {
 app: 'app/',
 dist: 'dist/'
};

var paths = {
  scripts: ['scripts/**/*.js', '!scripts/libs/**/*.js'],
  styles: ['styles/**/*.css'],
  html: ['index.html', '404.html'],
  views: ['views/**/*.html']
};


gulp.task('copy', ['clean'], function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.views, {cwd: bases.app, read:false})
  .pipe(gulp.dest(bases.dist + '/views/'));
});

gulp.task('clean', function() {
  return gulp.src(bases.dist, { read: false }) // much faster
    .pipe(rimraf());
});


gulp.task('usemin', ['clean'], function () {
  return gulp.src('./*.html', {cwd: bases.app})
    .pipe(usemin({
      js: [/*uglify(), rev()*/]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(bases.dist));
});

// Rerun the task when a file changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(path.join(bases.app, paths.scripts[0]), ['usemin']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['usemin', 'copy']);
```